# Oracle procedure with date parameter in SSRS

Tags: oracle, reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2008-r2, ssrs-2012

we have following Oracle procedure with date parameter:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE R_T.Test1 (
Test1 IN OUT Reports.rep_type,
date_parameter IN system_days.daytime%TYPE)
AS
BEGIN
OPEN Test1 FOR
 select * from
 (select 
       sum(max(case when code = 'C3_TOTAL_PROD' then NET_MASS_MTD_MTON else  null end )) C3_TOTAL_PROD_MTD_MASS_S1,
   sum(max(case when code = 'C4_TOTAL_PROD' then NET_MASS_MTD_MTON else  null end )) C4_TOTAL_PROD_MTD_MASS_S1,
   sum(max(case when code = 'S_TOTAL_PROD'  then NET_MASS_MTD_MTON else  null end )) S_TOTAL_PROD_MTD_MASS_S1
   from MV_D_MAS
   where production_day between trunc(Date_Parameter, 'YEAR') 
             and LAST_DAY(date_parameter)
   group by production_day
) a;
END;
```

We need to run this procedure in SSRS.
What would be Query text in SQL Server Reporting Services (SSRS) to get this procedure working with date parameter:

[image]

Thanks,
S

Comment: So how I can pass oracle procedure parameter to SSRS, I think it shold be defined in Query Text field?

Answer (score 0):

within your "dataset properties" window - select "stored procedure" and put in your sp: R_T.Test1

as for your "date_parameter" - you would need another sp and join it up using the "parameters" folder in the report data pane.

hope that helps.

[image]
[image]